# How to convert element to array in jsonb [Postresql]

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I need to convert some element in jsonb column to array

What I have:

```
{"a": {
          "b": "2022-11-03",
          "c": "321321",
          "d": "213321"
     }
}
```

What I need:
`

```
{"a": [
        {
          "b": "2022-11-03",
          "c": "321321",
          "d": "213321"
         }
      ]
}
```

Comment: You starting data is not valid JSON so edit it to be valid and represent what you are actually working with.

Comment: sorry, i updated my details. it was just an example

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `jsonb_set()` for this:

```
SELECT jsonb_set(the_column, '{a}', jsonb_build_array(the_column -> 'a'))
FROM the_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **"json_agg"** function.

```
select json_agg(DATA) from table_json
```

Example: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oY4u3l6X)

Answer (score 0):

Using function from here [JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) and the [The SQL/JSON Path Language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH). Use path language to decompose the original object and then jsonb_build_object to rebuild it in new form.

```
SELECT
    jsonb_build_object(
        (jsonb_path_query_array('{"a": {"b": "2022-11-03","c": "321321","d": "213321"}}', '$.keyvalue()') -> 0 -> 'key') ->> 0, 
        (jsonb_path_query_array('{"a": {"b": "2022-11-03","c": "321321","d": "213321"}}', '$.keyvalue()') -> 0 -> 'value' 
         || '[]'::jsonb));

jsonb_build_object                     
------------------------------------------------------------
 {"a": [{"b": "2022-11-03", "c": "321321", "d": "213321"}]}
```